# Archiva or Artifactory using something other than localhost

Tags: artifactory, archiva

I want to use either Archiva or Artifactory in stand-alone mode,
but I want to configure it to listen on something other than 'localhost'.

My internal repository is on a system between my internal network
and the Internet.

I want to configure either of these to listen on the internal IP address.

Is this possible?

TIA,
dave

Comment: your question is rather cryptic :) Here are some questions to clarify:
What do you mean "Stand-alone mode"?
"listen" means getting requests from?
what do you mean "internal ip address"?

Answer (score 0):

For archiva have a look at a file called jetty.xml
You will find a line

```
<Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host"/></Set>
```

Normally you can set with an ip or a host.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a newbie WRT Jetty and Tomcat, etc. Where in jetty.xml should I add this line? Or do I simply edit the existing line in the <Call name="addConnector"> block?

Comment: if you deploy inside Tomcat you must configure Tomcat files. Yup edit those line for Jetty.